# Accessing property of other class

Tags: objective-c, properties

I've got a UIViewController which has three views: Category -> Sub-Category -> Detail View. The content of the Sub-Category and Detail View depends on which row is clicked in the Category view. This is done with a property called 'categoryClicked' and is declared in the sub-category.m file. It's value is given in the category.m file by the following lines of code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    Sub-category *sub = [[Sub-category alloc] initWithNibName:@"Sub-category" bundle:nil];

    sub.categoryClicked = [_categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rubrieken animated:YES];

}
```

This works perfectly fine until I want to use the value of categoryClicked in the Detail View. In both the category.m and the DetailView.m sub-category.m is imported. For testing purposes I putted a label on the Detail View and in the DetailView.m file I've got the following code:

```
Sub-category *sub = [[Sub-category alloc] initWithNibName:@"Sub-category" bundle:nil];

label.text = sub.categoryClicked;
```

I'm convinced this code should do the job but in fact I get an empty label. Is there anybody able to tell me what I'm doing wrong.

**Edit**
categoryClicked is a property declared in Sub-category.h and synthesized in Sub-category.m.
Wanted to post some more code but there is no more relevant code.

Comment: Comment unrelated to below answer: you should try to follow objective-c naming conventions. Instead of `Sub-category` you should use `SubCategory` (or `Subcategory`).

Comment: I've got good naming conventions but it is in Dutch. To make it more clear for you I changed the names. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This line...

```
Sub-category *sub = [[Sub-category alloc] initWithNibName:@"Sub-category" bundle:nil];
```

...creates a new `Sub-category`.  Since it's new, it doesn't know anything about what information has been given to some other `Sub-category` object.  You need to get a reference to the existing object if you want to access its data.

Comment: Okay, that's new to me. Can you tell me how I get that reference?

Comment: It depends on how your original `Sub-category` and `Detail` objects are related.  (If `Sub-category` creates `Detail` then it can pass `self` into a `Detail` property.  If `Category` creates both, then **it** can set a `Detail` property to `sub`.)

Comment: Have you used an object-oriented language before @yoeriboven

Comment: How and where is the thing you're calling a detail view created?  (Is it a view or a view controller?)  Also, which class is your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` code in...Category?

Comment: The `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` code is in category.m. I created it this way: make a new file, in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` of sub-category.m I initialized an allocated it the same way as above and then I have `[self.navigationcontroller pushViewController:detailView animation:YES]`

Comment: So, if you create a `categoryClicked` property in the detail view **controller**, you should be able to write `detailView.categoryClicked = self.categoryClicked;` just before you push the detail view **controller**.  Then in its `viewWillAppear:` you can set its `label.text`.  That way, the data is passing from existing objects to new objects.

Comment: Shouldn't I first declare detailView the way it is done above?

Comment: I assumed from your earlier comment, where you said you used `pushViewController:detailView`, that `detailView` is already being declared and created.  Use it; don't create another one.

Comment: No, there's only `pushViewController:sub-category` since the code is in the category.m.

Comment: I'm quoting your own words back to you and you're telling me they're wrong.  I give up!

Comment: That `pushViewController:detailView` is in sub-category.m and the property I want to get in my detailView.m is in category.m. ;) In category.m 'detailView' isn't declared.

Answer (score 0):

When you `alloc` an object, you're allocating memory space for it. Then when you use something with `init` (like `initWithNibName`) you're initializing it. So when you allocate memory space for `sub` and initialize it, you have one object. But then you `alloc` and `init` again, which creates an entirely new (and completely unrelated) object. Make sure that you remove anything that could destroy your old object.

Also, the `*` symbol means that `sub` is a pointer (it points to a memory location). Whenever you use the assignment operator (`=`) you're telling it to point to a new thing. What you're doing is telling the `label.text` pointer to point at what `sub` is pointing at. But if you change what `sub` is pointing at and point `label.text` at the same thing, neither one is pointing at the value you want.

Hope this is clear enough, if it's not trying posting some more code and maybe someone can suggest exact changes.

**-EDIT-**

If you want to have a reference to an object you can only get it a few ways. What's important to know is that you can't really "create" a reference to an existing object. You have to have some connection to the object.

- Declare the object inside of the file you want the reference in with something like `Category c = [[Category alloc] init];` Remember this creates a new object, it won't create a reference to an existing object. However, creating the object inside of another object means that one "owns" the other and can do whatever it wants with it (obviously including accessing properties and calling methods).
- Use a "chain" of objects to get a reference to your object. So if your file owns a file that owns the object you want you can use `topfile.otherfile.objectyouwant`. The most obvious example of this is getting a reference to an object owned by a subview.

That's about as basic as it gets; just remember that there aren't any "global" objects that you can just call by name. If your problem isn't solved by this, either look at some sample code and try to figure out how references work, or post another question that's more closely related to your problem

Comment: Thanks, I get it. But unfortunately I don't get how I should do it right.

Comment: Post some more code. I think the problem is that you need something pointing at `sub` and you don't have anything. You should be declaring `sub` in `DetailView.m` if you want to access it later. Variables aren't even close to global in objective-c.

Comment: I tried to add some code, but there is no extra relevant code.

Comment: Well if your code is in two different files that's your problem. You're declaring `sub` in a place where you can't "see" it from your `DetailView` object. You need to either move your category code into the `DetailView` code or store a reference to your sub-category and then use `categoryPointer.categoryClicked`. Also, remove the `Sub-Category` allocation from your DetailView code; if your declaration is in another file, under no circumstances will this be correct.

Comment: The category code can't be in the DetailView code because it has to be in the Category file to create the TableView.

Comment: Then you need to store a reference to the Category file and reference category.sub

Comment: How? I probably know how to do it but I'm afraid I don't know the right word. Don't know how you create that reference.